# Accessing variables of a recycler viewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im trying to access variables in my inner class ViewHolder - how would I do it? I did the logic in the onBindViewHolder but I need to pass these values so I can use them.
I tried to access the variable in ViewHolder  and of course it I got null error because of different scope, how would i prevent this?

```
public class AcceptAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AcceptAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    ArrayList<Job> mAllJobs=new ArrayList<>();
    Timestamp timestamp;//retrieve timestamp from firestore
    Date javaDate;
    Calendar cal;


    public AcceptAdapter(ArrayList<Job> allJobs) {
        this.mAllJobs = allJobs;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.accepted_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);


        return viewHolder;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {



        holder.textView1.setText(mAllJobs.get(position).getJobTitle());
        timestamp =  mAllJobs.get(position).getStartTime();// retrive timestamp

        javaDate=timestamp.toDate();//converts timestamp to date
         cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(javaDate);//convert date to calendar

        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
        holder.textView2.setText(  String.valueOf(cal.getTime()));
        Log.d("this is time -", String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
        Log.d("this is time -", String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
        Log.d("this is time -", String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        Log.d("this is time -", String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
        Log.d("this is time -", String.valueOf(javaDate.getHours()));




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAllJobs.size();
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {


        TextView textView1, textView2;
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfMonth = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();




        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.JobTitle_textView);
            textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NumOfVacancies_textView);

        //how would i get to use cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) here so i can replace these numbers
           if (month == Calendar.SEPTEMBER  && dayOfMonth == 17 && year == 2021 && time.getHour() >= 16 && time.getHour() < 23) {
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.activateGEOFENCE).setEnabled(true);
            }
         else
           {
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.activateGEOFENCE).setEnabled(false);
           }



            itemView.findViewById(R.id.activateGEOFENCE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "this is the message");
                }
            });
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set values, Just initialize your xml views in the ViewHolders Constructor like this,

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    
    TextView textView1, textView2;
    'YourViewType' activateGEOFENCE
  
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.JobTitle_textView);
        textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NumOfVacancies_textView);
        activateGEOFENCE = itemView.findViewById(R.id.activateGEOFENCE);

    }
}
```

then set value in the views from onBindViewHolder method, the parameter 'holder' is the reference of your viewholder, you can access all of your initialized xml views from this holder parameter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textView1.setText(mAllJobs.get(position).getJobTitle());

    timestamp =  mAllJobs.get(position).getStartTime();// retrive timestamp

    javaDate=timestamp.toDate();//converts timestamp to date
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(javaDate);//convert date to calendar

    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
    holder.textView2.setText(  String.valueOf(cal.getTime()));
     
    if ('yourLogic') {

        holder.activateGEOFENCE.setEnabled(true);

    } else{

        holder.activateGEOFENCE.setEnabled(false);

    }

    holder.activateGEOFENCE.setOnClickListener(newView.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("TAG", "this is the message");
            }
        });


}
```